# Change seed for random numbers in Matlab when doing job array

Tags: matlab

I am running a Matlab job array using HPC. Each job performs a loop involving random numbers. I get the same random number in each job. How can I solve this issue and get different random numbers per job?

I have found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17164520/random-seed-across-different-pbs-jobs) but I think it is about a case more complicated than mine: instead of a `parfor` loop in each job, I have just a `for` loop.

Here a simplified version of my code

```
%%%% main.m %%%%%
clear all
n=5;
K=2; 
H=5; %number of jobs per worker

%%%% f.m %%%%%
RVall=zeros(n,K,H);
for s=1:H
    RVall(:,:,s) = unifrnd(0,1,n,K); 
end
filename = sprintf('RVall.%d.mat', ID);
save(filename, 'RVall')
```

The .sh file is

```
#Example

#$ -S /bin/bash
#$ -l h_vmem=4G
#$ -l tmem=4G
#$ -l h_rt=360:0:0
#$ -cwd
#$ -j y

#Run 200 tasks where each task has a different $SGE_TASK_ID ranging 
from 1 to 200
#$ -t 1-200

#$ -N try
date
hostname

#Output the Task ID
echo "Task ID is $SGE_TASK_ID"

matlab -nodisplay -nodesktop -nojvm -nosplash -r "main; ID = $SGE_TASK_ID; f; exit"
```

In this example, you'll see that `RVall.1=RVall.2=...=RVall.200`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer you refer to still applies. A simple workaround to start with would be to seed the random number generation in each run with a different seed using `rng(ID)`, e.g.:

```
%%%% main.m %%%%%
clear all
n=5;
K=2; 
H=5; %number of jobs per worker

%%%% f.m %%%%%
rng(ID);
RVall=zeros(n,K,H);
for s=1:H
    RVall(:,:,s) = unifrnd(0,1,n,K); 
end
filename = sprintf('RVall.%d.mat', ID);
save(filename, 'RVall')
```

Reason: MATLAB's random number generator is set to default values at startup, namely the Mersenne-Twister algorithm with seed 0. The sequence of random numbers will be the same for all your runs unless you set a different seed in each run.